# D-Link DIR-685 and WD Scorpio Blue 1TB, 750GB, 640GB

Tags: external-hard-drive

Has anyone tried installing the WD Scorpio Blue 640gb, 750gb or 1TB 2.5" drives into the D-Link DIR-685? That drives a bit thicker than standard 2,5" HDD (12,5 mm instead of 9,5 mm) and I'm not sure that it fit into DIR-685.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definitely will NOT fit.